# Metal only draws to a portion of the view and inquiry about layers

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am following the setup for a basic metal tutorial and am trying to render a blank screen of uniform color.

For some reason I am getting this issue where Metal only draws to a part of the screen.

I set up a single view application and attached the MainStoryboard's view to a class I am creating. I set its background color to green.

Here is the class

```
class MBEMetalView: UIView {

    var device:MTLDevice?
    var MTLLayer:CAMetalLayer?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

        //The book said to cast the layer to a CAMetalLayer 
        //but that causes a crash in the redraw method because
        //failed assertion `No rendertargets set in RenderPassDescriptor.'
        //So we do this.. which might be wasteful?
        MTLLayer = CAMetalLayer()
        MTLLayer?.device = device
        MTLLayer?.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm
        MTLLayer?.framebufferOnly = true
        MTLLayer?.frame = frame
        layer.addSublayer(MTLLayer!)
    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        redraw()
    }

    func redraw() {
        var drawable = MTLLayer?.nextDrawable()
        var texture = drawable?.texture

        var passDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadAction.clear
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreAction.store
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 1, 0, 1)


        var commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()
        var commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
        var commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: passDescriptor)
        commandEncoder?.endEncoding()

        if let drawOn = drawable {
            commandBuffer?.present(drawOn)
            commandBuffer?.commit()
        }
    }

}
```

The class should have rendered the entire screen green however this is not the case it only fills up a portion as shown by this picture from an iPhone 6s plus (Red is the background of the view not what Metal is drawing).
[image]

This result brings to mind a few questions:

1. Why is Metal only rendering to a portion of the screen
2. The tutorial I am following is doing it in Objective-C they were able to cast the layer of the inherited UIView as a CAMetal layer
   rather than creating a new layer (this allowed them to remove the
   `.addSublayer` line). However when I try this I get a crash that is
   shown in the comments? Why is this?
3. How will the frame passed in be effected by devices with a safe area like an iPhone X? Will I have to something extra to draw
   outside of the safe area? Where can I get the dimensions of the safe
   area from my view's frame programmatically (incase new devices are
   released)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `CAMetalLayer`'s frame in `init(coder)` and never change it. But in `init(coder)` the final frame size is not known yet (it's just using whatever size you set in Interface Builder at this point but not the device size yet). In `didMoveToWindow()`, also set the frame of the Metal layer to its final size. (Or perhaps in `layoutSubviews()`.)

Comment: Thankyou for this answer. Could you also try to answer the 2nd and 3rd parts of the question? The most important part of the question you answered but I still have some questions lingering

Comment: I don't know the answer to part 3 (haven't done any drawing with Metal on the iPhone X yet). For part 2, I'd need to see the actual complete code that causes the issue.